# Can't get suds to read my load balancer's SOAP API

Tags: python, api, soap, suds

I'm very new to SOAP and am just trying to get the basics working with "suds". I'm running the following code:

```
import sys
from suds.client import Client
url='http://loadbalancer/wsdl/sys_service.wsdl'
client = Client(url)
```

If I run 'print client' in my interpreter, I get the following:

```
Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4.1 (beta)  build: R705-20101207
Service ( AdcSysInfo ) tns="urn:webservicesapi"
Prefixes (1)
  ns0 = "urn:webservicesapi"
Ports (1):
  (AdcSysInfoSOAP)
     Methods (61):
    ....
    (many methods come back, truncated the output)
    getCPU()
    ....
```

I just want to focus on the getCPU method for now, so I run this statement in my interpreter:

```
example = client.service.getCPU()
```

But I get the following output back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 542, in __call__
return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 602, in invoke
result = self.send(soapenv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 643, in send
reply = transport.send(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/transport/https.py", line 64, in send
return  HttpTransport.send(self, request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 77, in send
fp = self.u2open(u2request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 118, in u2open
return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 414, in _open
'unknown_open', req)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1223, in unknown_open
raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: urlprefix>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Could it be you need an https url to use the service?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds-jurko ?

It may be more up-to-date than plain suds.